Время выполнения скрипта увеличивается пропорционально количеству значениям в списке
в питоне новичок, собрал скрипт. Если в списке tickers 5-10-20 монеток - обновляется ежесекундно, но если их там 200-300 и более - обновляется раз в минуту
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать получение данных из API раз в секунду?
from time import sleep
tickers = ['BTCUSDT','ETHUSDT','BCHUSDT','МОНЕТА50', 'МОНЕТА В МАССИВЕ #950', 'МОНЕТА В МАССИВЕ #3500']


while i > 0:
    oi_data = {}

    for ticker in tickers:
        oi_data[ticker] = float(um_futures_client.open_interest(ticker)['openInterest'])
    i += 1

    if i == 2:
        myarray = oi_data
    sleep(0.1)

    if i > 2:
        for tickerval, tickername in enumerate(tickers):
            if ((oi_data[tickername] / myarray[tickername] - 1) * 100) > 5:
                print('сработало')
                myarray[tickername] = oi_data[tickername]

            if oi_data[tickername] < myarray[tickername]:
                print('сработало')
                myarray[tickername] = oi_data[tickername]


зачем тебе enumerate, если tickerval нигде не используется?

Может у клиента есть вариант запроса сразу по всем тикерам? Да и requests.get(oiupsms) непонятно что такое, может не нужно его на каждой итерации цикла дёргать?

запрашивать сразу несколько тикеров нельзя, эта проблема решилась применением sleep

tickerval применяется, тут не указал его применение чтобы не растягивать код

а что тут сделать... Если труба пропускает только 5 литров воды в секунду, то 50 литров в секунду ты там никак не протолкнешь.
